# Detail template with locking feature in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I tried using the frozen columns and detail template both at a time but both they are not supported at a time by kendo telerik grid I get this error every time when I try:

```
 'Uncaught Error: Having both detail template and locked columns is not supported'.
```

Could you please look into this error. Would you give me an idea, how could I achieve both detail template and frozen columns together in kendo.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-column-locking-with-detail-template

Shankar

Comment: Please put code of detail template to check what is the problem, no one can assume why the error appears.

Comment: I have just updated my question with a reference of a link. Hope it might clear now.

Answer (score 1):

As conflicting nature it's not possible in kendo ( or either grid . e.g. Excel sheet too )
http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/6263744-support-row-templates-with-frozen-columns

one probable solution is :

- Create two grids side by side. ( left grid for frozen column , right grid for details columns ) you can use same dataSource for both the grid .
- Make div size fixed so user cannot scroll on left grid .
- hide those repeating columns in Right grid.
- add one more extra expand button column in left grid.
- on click of expand button of left grid, expand appropriate right side detail row.

  i know this is not actual solution with kendo and lots of code work around, but using jquery, tricks you can at least achieve up to certain level.

=> if you have any solution then please share it here sankar. looks like this is old post .